# axacropdflib - set source from worker thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, pdf, worker-thread

I have a vb.net project which has a treeview of pdf's on the left and the acrobat AxAcroPDF viewer control on the right. Click a item in the treeview, I get the fileinfo.fullname value and pass that over to the AxAcroPDF src property.

While testing I noticed that pdf's were slow to load and would block my ui thread so I decided that a workerthread would be a good helper to lazy load these pdf's in the background.

When I run my code with the worker thread's DoWork method and it tries to update my pdfviewer object I get an invalid cast exception.

> System.InvalidCastException was caught   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to
>   interface type 'AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{3B813CE7-7C10-4F84-AD06-9DF76D97A9AA}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
>          at AcroPDFLib.IAcroAXDocShim.set_src(String pVal)
>          at AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.set_src(String value)
>          at myapp.fill_treeview_with_filesfolders_docked_andthreads.LoadPDFInBackground(String
>   selectedfile) in
>   C:\Users\me\Desktop.....\fill_treeview_with_filesfolders_docked_andthreads.vb:line
>   84   InnerException:

I can't find any other threads online with this exception detail so I am not sure what the issue is here. I thought my problem had to do with a cross thread access violation but even if I set Control.Checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls to false I get the same exception. It didn't make sense to me that I would check for invokerequired from the DoWork routine anyways because the point of my worker thread is to handle the load for me, not shove it back into the UI thread.

Can anyone recommend a workaround that I can try to achieve what I am after here?

my Code:

The treeview afterselect is wired to displayfile

```
 AddHandler TreeView.AfterSelect, AddressOf displayfile

 Private Sub displayfile(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)
    Try

        Dim selectedfile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(e.Node.Tag) 'tag has our full path embedded.

        'todo: Future - consider type of the file and load a pre-made panel with appropriate host object
        If selectedfile.Extension.ToLower.Equals(".pdf") Then
            'show "loading...."
            LoadingPanel.BringToFront()
            backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedfile.FullName)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Background Worker Stuff:

```
#Region "Background Worker Events"
' This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done. 
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundworker.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    e.Result = LoadPDFInBackground(e.Argument)
End Sub

' This event handler updates the progress. 
Private Sub backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles backgroundworker.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

' This event handler deals with the results of the background operation. 
Private Sub backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles backgroundworker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Result Then
        'hide loading panel and show pdf panel
        pdfviewer.BringToFront()
    Else
        'what to do if failed to load???
    End If
End Sub
#End Region

  Private Function LoadPDFInBackground(ByVal selectedfile As String) As Boolean
    Try
        pdfviewer.src = selectedfile
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Any chance you can state what line the error is thrown at?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg: the only line # I see in the stack trace is 81. That line is the "pdfviewer.src = selectedfile" line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, but try changing this line:

```
pdfviewer.src = selectedfile
```

to the following:

```
If pdfviewer.InvokeRequired Then
    pdfviewer.Invoke(Sub() pdfviewer.src = selectedfile)
```

It might work around the error. Interesting to see if it does.

Comment: Well, that works. I wonder why turning off control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls had no effect but this one did?  By calling invoke am I actually jumping to the ui thread context or just grabbing the handle? I don't do much multi-threaded stuff so behind the scenes I don't really know what it's doing.

Comment: Unfortunately this does hand the processing back to the UI (I think). The only way around this would to have the pdfveiwer object created on the worker thread, which would mean recreating the object every time a new pdf is loaded.

Comment: You can probably check if it hands it back simply by timing the code. Give it a whirl with the stopwatch class.

Comment: I did an update to a label directly following my call to start the worker thread and it waited until the entire pdf loaded before updating the label. So it looks like it completely jumps over to the UI thread. Guess I will have to find a pdf control that supports a stream object as I can fill/return one of those from a worker thread just as easily. Thanks for your help FraserOfSmeg

Comment: btw, tried to instantiate and return the pdf com object from the workerthread and it throws an exception because it has to run on a single threaded apartment type thread.